# REGEX using Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Using pandas and python: I am attempting to create a new column that displays '1' if a regular expression appears in some other specified column.

For example, I would like to create a new column titled 'Rheum', which takes on a value of '1' if the expression '391.1' appears in a corresponding column 'ICD' per row. In some rows of the ICD column there are cells which have a variety of expressions in the form '424.1, 391.1, 420.2, etc'.

So far I have:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('example_worksheet.csv')

def ICD(c):
    if c[df['ICD9'].apply(str).str.contains('391.1', na=False)] == True:
        return '1'
    else:
        return '0'

df['Rheum'] = df.apply(ICD, axis=1)
```

Example data frame:

Sure! Example data frame:

```
Patient   ICD9    
123        424.1, 391.1, 420.2
323        390.8, 420.2, 260
454        391.1, 424.2
```

However, this code results in a new column 'Rheum' with only '0's at every row.

Comment: Could you post part of your dataframe?

Comment: Sure! Example data frame:

Patient   ICD9    
123        424.1, 391.1, 420.2
323        390.8, 420.2, 260
454        391.1, 424.2

Comment: Please edit your question with your data as dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.contains` return bool values. You could convert it to integer with simple add 0:

```
df['Rheum'] = df.ICD.str.contains('391.1') + 0
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data ="""
Patient   ICD9    
123        424.1, 391.1, 420.2
323        390.8, 420.2, 260
454        391.1, 424.2
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=' \s+')
df['Rheum'] = df.ICD9.str.contains('391.1') + 0

In [122]: df
Out[122]: 
   Patient                 ICD9  Rheum
0      123  424.1, 391.1, 420.2      1
1      323    390.8, 420.2, 260      0
2      454         391.1, 424.2      1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Anton!

If 'data' is coded as a CSV file with columns 'patient' and 'ICD9', is there a way to import the CSV and work with the code you suggested?

Comment: Yes, you could use `df = pd.read_csv('your_file', names=['patient', 'ICD9'])` and then operate with that df

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.contains`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3],'ICD':['424.1, 391.1, 420.2, etc','ABV','391.1']})

df['Rheum'] = df.ICD.str.contains('391.1').astype(int)

#Out[7]: 
#                        ICD  col1  Rheum
#0  424.1, 391.1, 420.2, etc     1      1
#1                       ABV     2      0
#2                     391.1     3      1
```

Comment: If the csv file that I load automatically imports the ICD column as int type, how can I convert to string for this task?

Comment: @AMS You could do that with method of dataframe and series `astype(str)`

Comment: Maybe using `df['ICD'].apply(str)` ... please try to do some search before